# How to avoid asset messages in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

```
Started GET "/assets/reset.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /reset.css - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/style.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /style.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Started asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 70.63.17.68 at Wed Oct 12 20:10:49 +0000 2011
Served asset /application.js - 200 OK (1ms)
```

I would like to avoid this messages and if I turned off debug mode as,

```
config.assets.debug = off
```

the asset files will serve as concatenated.

Is there anyway to get rid of this messages as well as asset should serve seperate asset files.

Answer (score 1):

On your gemfile use `gem 'quiet_assets'`

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

config/initializers/quite_assets.rb

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
    Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
      def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
        previous_level = Rails.logger.level
        Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ %r{^/assets/}
        call_without_quiet_assets(env)
      ensure
        Rails.logger.level = previous_level
      end
    alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
  end
end
```